# How to Refresh Current Activity once after load?

Tags: android, android-activity

How to refresh current Activity 1 time after load? My code refresh the activity, but in Loop.

This site have some examples, but most is after click button. Isn't my case.

My code is:

```
finish();startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: Why do you want to refresh your activity? Your question isn't clear. You can use a lot of kind of timer but refreshing the whole activity is a bad thing I think. You could update related views.

Comment: @EfeAYDIN cuz refresh activity is best way for my app in this moment.. isn't the best way, but solve the problemem... Im new in android world  and dont know how to do advanced programming.

Comment: @EfeAYDIN Im scraping a page via Jsoup... but the page has a reload button that i need to click via javascript first before showing the information. I already do all this, but to display the updated information I need refresh the activity. U got it?

Comment: If you write the code above in your onCreate() method without any if else statement, it will be in a loop. You need some condition to break it but I think there is no scenario to restart your activity in your onCreate() method. Tell us what do you exactly want and share your all codes related to question.

Comment: Code above can not be the reason the loop if it is in an onClick() method of a button. Share the code.

Comment: @EfeAYDIN its part of my code

Answer (score 2):

just do this way.

```
  startActivity(getIntent()); 
  finish();
```

Comment: i think you need to put this on your onlick, or after the loop or if you have another method that will refresh your activity.

Comment: This code refresh the page, but it stays in loop... I need only 1 refresh after Activity load complete. How do I get this code to run only once?

Comment: add this in your onPost.

Comment: when is your process finish loading? And do you have a button to just reload your activity? Add 1 button to your activity and put this code to refresh your activity.

Comment: The button works well... when I clickON refresh the activity... but, code isn't the problem... I only need to auto refresh the Activity with this code only once when the Activity starts... u got it?

Comment: do u understand what i need?

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String url;

```
//initializing WebView
private WebView mwebView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Div1().execute();

    String tag = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tag");

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    url = "https://xxxxxxxx.com/profile/"+tag+"";

    //WebView
    mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve webView performance
    mwebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    //mwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    mwebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


    mwebView.loadUrl("https://xxxxxxxx.com/profile/"+tag+"");

    //force links open in webview only
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());
}

private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {



        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("xxxxxxxx.com/profile/\"+tag+\"")){


            return false;
        }
        else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }}

// Div1 AsyncTask
private class Div1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
```

super.onPreExecute();

```
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        mwebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                "l=document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[1];"+
                "e=document.createEvent('MouseEvent');"+
                "e.initEvent('click',true, true);"+
                "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
                "})()");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK2);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(getIntent());
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this your answer or question?

Comment: @SatanPandeya ... its an E.g for G.Dator ....the code to refresh works well with button..but.. I need only 1 refresh in current Activity after load complete,

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code I wrote:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


static boolean isInit = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(isInit) {
        isInit = false;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        Log.d("Restart", "asdasda");
    }

}
```

}

One thing I need to say is that if you start this activity from another activity, in every call you need set the isInit variable true like this:

```
MainActivity.isInit = true;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
```

Using "getIntent()" instead of "new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)" cause closing the application after logging "Restart" text.

I don't know whether it is what you want (I think this can not be any solution of any problem). I still think better is reload only views.