# How to send data from an activity which received data using getIntent()?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity which uses an Adapter and RecyclerView to display a number of contacts to the user (activity A). The user can tap on a contact to view its info (activity B). They may then choose to edit that info; for this the user is taken to EditContact (activity C).

Is it possible to use `startActivityForResult()` in activity B to edit the database information in activity C and update the database and layout of activity B on `RESULT_OK`?

**EDIT**
Adding code snippets for clarity:

New/Edit Contact activity:

```
// Pass the data to the ViewContact activity
Intent addNewContact = new Intent();
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, name);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_SURNAME, surname);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_COMPANY, company);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumbers);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_TYPE, phoneTypes);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL_TYPE, emailTypes);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, addresses);
addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_POSTCODE, postcode);
[...]

if (name.length() > 0 && phoneNumbers.length() > 0) {
    if (id != -1) {
        addNewContact.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
    }
    setResult(RESULT_OK, addNewContact);
    onBackPressed(); // or finish()
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter at least a name and phone no.", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

ViewContact activity:

```
// On successful result, add the new contact & update the UI
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == EDIT_CONTACT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            int id = data.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
            // Check ID != -1 just in case, which shouldn't happen
            if (id == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Contact not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String name = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
            String surname = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SURNAME);
            String company = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_COMPANY);
            String phoneNumber = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            String phoneType = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_PHONE_TYPE);
            String email = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_EMAIL);
            String emailType = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_EMAIL_TYPE);
            String address = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_ADDRESS);
            String postcode = data.getStringExtra(AddNewContact.EXTRA_POSTCODE);

            Contact contact =
                    new Contact(
                            name,
                            surname,
                            company,
                            phoneNumber,
                            phoneType,
                            email,
                            emailType,
                            address,
                            postcode);
            contact.setId(id);

            // TODO - this does not work, must use LiveData?
            // Update the database
            ContactRepository contactRepository = new ContactRepository(getApplication());
            contactRepository.update(contact);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: If someone downvotes this, it would be nice to get an explanation as to why, because this has been puzzling me.

Comment: Questions asking for the "best" way to do something are primarily opinion-based and thus off-topic, unless they contain a precise, unambiguous, objective definition to measure "bestness".

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you, will update my question to be more specific.

Comment: See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#5

Comment: Add some of your code and log details

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh hi Avinsh, yes I have added some snippets. I understand that the proper way to tackle this is by using LiveData, as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In Activity B, you can to start EditContact activity as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditContact.class);
intent.putExtra(EditContact.EXTRA_CONTACT_ITEM, contactItem);
startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

When you're done editing the contact in EditContact activity, return  `RESULT_OK` with edited contactItem and finish the activity:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CONTACT_ITEM, contactItem);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Then, in Activity B, handle the results as follow:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == EDIT_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ContactItem contactItem= data.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_CONTACT_ITEM);
                //Store item in database
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add `contactItem` to the data in the `Intent` and pass it in `setResult`

Comment: Ok so I've tried this, and the entry in the database is updated using `ContactViewModel contactViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContactViewModel.class);` and `contactViewModel.update(contact);`. However, the UI of Activity B does not update to display the newly added data - it stays the same as before (which is expected as I am only resuming it). Is there a way to refresh the activity? Should I run `onCreate()` again?

Comment: Activity B's onResume() should be called when you come back to it, so you need to override this method and refresh your UI

Comment: @matdev Yes, both onRestart() and onResume() are called. I've tried overriding and calling again the layout inflater, but my app crashes. I've also tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579788/how-to-refresh-current-activity-once-after-load) without any luck. It would be nice if I could re-create the activity, if possible. Also, the activity to be refreshed (activity B) gets its information from activity A, so recreating it without firing the intent from A means the required info will be null..

Comment: No need to call the inflater again. You should be able to refresh your UI in Activity B's onActivityResult() . What happens when you do so ?

Comment: @matdev Ok I think I'm doing it wrong because I am calling the viewModel on activity B. The database only updates when I go back to activity A. If I get that fixed (i.e. update the database properly, using LiveData or otherwise), then maybe the UI will update accordingly. I just need to understand LiveData.

Comment: ok, please accept my answer if it helped solving the initial issue